# Best way to edit all custom variable values and re-import

Tags: channel-entries, cartthrob, custom-fields, import, export

running ExpressionEngine with Cartthrob - we've come up against a situation where the client has requested to remove a global Tax setting, so that they can have all prices on the site already inclusive of VAT.

The price is currently set as a custom variable, alongside some other custom variables for previous price settings and others (we inherited this site from another dev team). Our problem is that we now need to add 20% to all prices, to bring them in line with correct pricing now there is no global tax in effect.

What is the best way of achieving this, in a way that doesn't involve manually changing each product entry? My initial thought was to perform an export of the dataset (CSV or otherwise) for products, create a calculation in the resulting file to generate new prices, and then reimport into EE. I tried exporting by creating a custom export template with download csv headers, but it resulted in an empty export. I also tried looking to the database for manipulating via sql, but of course the custom variables are not stored within a flat table structure.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated - worth noting I do need to be able to import this back in at the end of the process too! Thanks in advance,

Ben

Answer (score 0):

How were the actual variables being declared or set to begin with? Were they being set in the CP or a master configuration file?

Comment: I'm virtually certain that they're being set in the CP - I can certainly create new ones from there, and there are no references to any custom field `$assign_to_config` variables in either the config or index master files.